# Changing the background color behind a selected substring in a Firemonkey TMemo component

Tags: firemonkey, tmemo

I wish to programmatically set focus on a particular substring in a (Delphi 10.3.1) Firemonkey TMemo component, by painting a yellow background behind the substring. The code below paints a yellow rectangle in the right position, but the rectangle appears to be superimposed over the text, thereby hiding it. Is there some TMemo property that can be used to avoid this? If not, what is the recommended fix?

```
procedure TTextGUIMemo.SetFocusOnHit(HitIndex: integer);
var
  LineIndex: integer;
  GlobalHitInterval: TIntegerArray2;
begin
  FFileCptHitsExpd.FileCptHits.GetHitSubstringGlobal(HitIndex, {=>}LineIndex,
                GlobalHitInterval);
  FMemo.SetFocus;
  FMemo.SelStart:= GlobalHitInterval[0];
  FMemo.SelLength:= GlobalHitInterval[1];
  FMemo.SelectionFill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Yellow; 
  FMemo.FontColor:= TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  FMemo.Repaint;
end;
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at (XE7) `FMX.Memo.pas` `procedure TMemo.DoContentPaint()` one might think the order of drawing is wrong. On the other hand it might be intentional, maybe I just don't get it why.

First the text is drawn, then the selection and finally spell highlighting. The standard selection color is `$7F3399FF`. Note the alpha channel (`7F`). This makes it half transparent and therefore the text shows through, even though the selection color is drawn over the text.

[image]

The solution for your issue is therefore to define the color to be partly transparent, f.ex.:

```
FMemo.SelectionFill.Color := $7FFFFF00; // or perhaps even more transparent $4FFFFF00
```

The effect of this is however, that the text is not black anymore (just as it isn't with the original selection color).

[image]

Testing with a copy of the `FMX.Memo.pas` file I rearranged the `procedure TMemo.DoContentPaint()` so that the code block marked with `// selection` comes before the `// text` block. In this case completely opaque color can be used for selection.

```
FMemo.SelectionFill.Color := $FFFFFF00; // alpha = $FF
```

[image]

**But never modify any file in the original Delphi installation directory(ies)**. Make a copy of the file in your project directory and modify that copy. The downside is that with new updated versions you might need to remember to copy and modify again.

Comment: Thank you - your suggestion of using a semi-transparent color is more than good enough for my application! I was wondering whether if in FMX graphics one can do the equivalent of setting PenMode to pmNotXor or any other of the TPenMode enumerated type values as in Vcl graphics. Using this facility makes painting and unpainting a cursor block a breeze.